# Is there a way to know the creation time of a file in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

i am using ubuntu and want to know the creation time of a file even when it gets modified or accessed ?

Comment: What file system, ext3 perhaps ?

Comment: I just noticed that in ext4 (not sure about other FS), if you list with "ls -li" (to list inodes), it seems to display the creation date. I didn't found any reference to it, so maybe I'm wrong (at least it seems to work for me).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately Unix does not store the creation time of a file.

All you are able to get using **[stat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/stat.2.html)** is

1. time of last access
2. time of last modification
3. time of last status change

**Note:** When using filesystem type **ext4** [crtime](http://tecadmin.net/file-creation-time-linux/) is available!

Comment: Links regarding ext4 crtime please.

Comment: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/12121  or  http://www.qa.com/about-qa/blogs/2010/july/creation-time-in-unix-yes---in-ext4

Comment: All the links are broken.

Comment: @jilagre: i removed the broken links

Comment: Links are broken again in the comments

Comment: looks like they are not

Answer (score 5):

This little script can get the creation date for ext4:

```
#!/bin/sh

fn=`realpath $1`
echo -n "Querying creation time of $1..."
sudo debugfs -R "stat $fn" /dev/sda4|grep crtime
```

I named it `fcrtime` and put it in my `~/bin` folder.
So in any folder I can use the command like: `fcrtime example.odp`

Example output:

`crtime: 0x5163e3f0:12d6c108 -- Tue Apr  9 12:48:32 2013`

Compared to stat-ing the same file:

```
  File: `example.odp'
  Size: 54962       Blocks: 112        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 11019246    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   fulop)   Gid: ( 1000/   fulop)
Access: 2013-04-09 13:20:05.263016001 +0300
Modify: 2013-04-09 13:20:05.227016001 +0300
Change: 2013-04-09 13:20:05.227016001 +0300
 Birth: -
```

**NOTES**

1. `realpath` is usually not installed by default. In Ubuntu eg. install it with `sudo apt-get install realpath`
2. Replace `/dev/sda4` if necessary with the one you get from `mount|grep ext4`

Comment: realpath does not seem to resolve the location correctly for files in /home if /home is a separate partition. A file named /home/user/fname should be resolved as user/fname.

Comment: I don't see `realpath` should do that. It is a utility to convert a filename to an absolute pathname (see `man realpath`). What you're looking for is the filename relative to the partition. I'm not aware of a tool like that but it probably exists out in the wild.

Comment: Other than that you're right, my script doesn't work if the target file is on a separate partition

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing that out for anyone seeking to use your script. Other than that issue, it works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The closest attribute available is the "change time", also known as `ctime`. This is updated for various system calls, any that modify the inode, rather than the data it contains.

```
matt@stanley:~$ stat -c %z .bashrc 
2010-08-17 11:53:56.865431072 +1000
```

### Links

- [stat(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)
- [stat(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat)

Comment: @AttilaFulop: Duh. That's why I said "the closest", and go into very specific detail how it differs from the creation time.

Comment: ctime is change time, not creation time! The question was about creation time. Change time is absolutely not useful for anyone looking for creation time.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems, this is available for ext4, btfrs, FAT, NTFS, and UDF filesystems, plus some others you're unlikely to encounter. It's not available on ext2 or ext3, probably the most common file system formats in Ubuntu.

You'll need a kernel patch, though: http://lwn.net/Articles/394391/. Apparently this is because Linus rejected creation time attribute on the grounds that somebody called it an "otime" and somebody else called it a "btime", and therefore the idea must be useless.

Answer (score 1):

Creation time, is known as file **Birth time** and is supported **on some filesystem, with some kernels only**. The command would be [Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91205/16640) answer:

```
stat --printf='%w' yourfile   #human readable

stat --printf='%W' yourfile   #seconds from Epoch , 0 if unknown
```

Note: this question is a duplicate of [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/16640). Also, make sure to read this question [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/16640).

Answer (score -3):

Yup - stat(): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man2/stat.2.html

Comment: ctime is change time, not creation time!

Answer (score -3):

guys i just finished writing this script this script to find the creation date of a file using perl:

```
use File::stat;
if (  scalar( @ARGV ) == 0 ) {
 die("type  a file  name  ex:perl filestat.pl <filename>");    
}
my $filename =  $ARGV[0] ;
my @info = stat($filename);
print "Creation time :",scalar localtime stat($filename)->ctime;
print "\n";
```

Comment: This is NOT returning creation time.

Comment: Agreed with @theTinMan, this code returns the change time, not the creation time.