# Ubuntu 11.10 file system does not implement creationTime?

Tags: java, filesystems, unix-timestamp

From the following quote taken from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#creationTime%28%29).

> FileTime creationTime() Returns the creation time. The creation time
>   is the time that the file was created. If the file system
>   implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time when
>   the file was created then this method returns an implementation
>   specific default value, typically the last-modified-time or a FileTime
>   representing the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).
>
> Returns: a FileTime representing the time the file was created

I get the last-modified-time instead of the creation time. 
Is anybody else, having ubuntu 11.10, confirming that actually the Ubuntu 11.10 file system does not implement that function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813541/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-creation-time-of-a-file-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the filesystem, ext3 doesn't store the creation time.
Ext4 does have a field 'crtime' that holds this information.
ext4 has been the default filesystem in Ubuntu since 9.10, so you probably have a ext4 filesystem.

**edit:**
Ok, apparently on Unix filesystems you cannot retrieve the creation timestamp, you simply get a copy of the last modification time.

In UnixFileAttributes.java:

```
@Override
public FileTime creationTime() {
    return lastModifiedTime();
}
```