# Recursively replace linux file and folder names such as "%m-%d-%y.tar" with their actual creation month/day/year

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733669/rename-file-command-in-unix-with-timestamp) but with its original creation date instead of the current date.

Example: This folder (output below is from Linux command `ls -ltr`)

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 backup_user backup_user 4096 Apr 26 01:06 "%m-%d-%y"
```

would have its file name changed to "04-26-20".

Comment: `Apr 26` is not creation date.

Comment: And you need to think how you will treat two directories with same date. And do you consider a tar-file a directory?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "creation" time in Linux.  Some unix like OSes do have a "birth" timestamp

Comment: Whether a creation date is available to you depends on used filesystem. See: [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/74329)

Comment: @Cyrus - but as long as a `cp`,`mv` or `tar` ignores that the thing is still completely academic ... it only has validity if the file remains on the FS it was created on, and in the case of `ext4`, for instance, you need debug tools to get at that value ... while my statement above is an oversimplification I still think it's valid ;)

Comment: sorry...meant modification time (in my case it won't be modified otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are some information missing I try to make assumptions and show a possible solution approach in general.

As already mentioned within the comments, for a filesystem like EXT3 there would be no [creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813541/). It might be possible to use the modification time which could be gathered via the `stat` command, i.e.

```
MTIME=$(stat --format="%y" \"%m-%d-%y\" | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

... or even access time or change time.

The date of `MTIME` is given in format `%Y-%m-%d` and can be changed for the new file name via

```
FNAME=$(date -d ${MTIME} +%m-%d-%y)
```

Than it it is possible to rename the directory, i.e.

```
mv \"%m-%d-%y\" ${FNAME}
```

which will of course change the timestamps within the filesystem for the directory.